# How to read list in JSON file using awk and sed

Tags: awk, sed, grep, json

I have a list in JSON file `apps.json`:

```json
{
"properites":{
   "apps":["apple","orange","mango"]
}
}
```

I need to read this file and get of objects.

I used:

```bsh
fwk_app = $( awk '/apps/{ print }' ${apps.json} | grep apps | awk -F: '{ print } substr($0, index($0,$2))}' |sed 's/(,*\)"[/\"]*$/\1/' );
for item in fwk_app:
do
echo"$item"
done
```

The output is:

```
mango
```

The output I need is:

```
apple
orange
mango
```

Comment: Use a proper json parser, such as `jq`. Everything else is just a recipe for headaches.

Comment: `jq -r '.properites.apps[]' apps.json` (using the misspelling from the example)

Comment: @uncle Billy is Jq -r i got same output ["apple","orange","mango"]

Comment: @ShravyaVaggu You would get that if you forgot to add the `[]` at the end of the `jq` expression. You want each individual element of the list, not the list as a whole.

Comment: i want to out put as: apple orange mango

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` you can get `the expected output`

```
awk -v FS=':' -v OFS='\n' '/"apps"/ {gsub(/[]"[]/,"",$2);split($2,a,/,/);print a[1],a[2],a[3]}' file
apple
orange
mango
```

but I think the correct way is @Kusalananda's solution.

Comment: thanks@Carlos it works . But i have doubt in print a[1],a[2],a[3] it prints only three indexs if add objects in list in future then i need add a[4] . but i don't want add this indexs for add i want direct list can you please help on this

Comment: If you want an output as: `apple orange mango` you can test it: `awk -v FS=':' '/"apps"/ {gsub(/[]"[]/,"",$2);split($2,a,/,/);print a[1],a[2],a[3]}' file`

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to parse a JSON file is to use a JSON parser.  The [`jq` utility](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is one such parser that is made for use on the command line and in scripts:

```bsh
jq -r '.properites.apps[]' apps.json
```

This would output

```
apple
orange
mango
```

This asks `jq` to extract the elements of the array `apps` in the top-level object `properites` in the JSON document in the file `apps.json`.
The `-r` option asks `jq` to output "raw" data rather than JSON-encoded data.

To get tab-delimited output on a single line, use

```bsh
jq -r '.properites.apps | @tsv' file
```

This would output

```
apple   orange  mango
```

The `@tsv` operator takes an array and outputs it as a tab-delimited list. You could instead use `@csv` to get properly quoted CSV output.

Note that this would also work no matter whether your JSON document was

```json
{
  "properites": {
    "apps": [
      "apple",
      "orange",
      "mango"
    ]
  }
}
```

or

```json
{"properites":{"apps":["apple","orange","mango"]}}
```

(these are equivalent forms of the same JSON document).

Comment: tried but i didnot get expected output

Comment: @ShravyaVaggu Then, 1) you used another command than what I showed, or 2) you have a JSON document that looks different to what's in your question, or 3) you may be expecting something other than what you say in the question.  Consider helping me determine what's wrong by letting me know what happened when you tried.

Comment: i am using the same command2) i have same JSON document as shown 3) i am expecting to list of objects i have rechecked all the three points you mentioned

Comment: so, what output are you getting then?

Comment: output:["apple","orange","mango"]  expected output : apple orange mango

Comment: Works fine for me. You are not using same command then, might be you are missing the `[]`?

Comment: Using the same input and `jq` invocation as Kusalananda, I also get the expected output, i.e. the three fruit, one per line. When I leave out the `[]` from the filter, I get [
  "apple",
  "orange",
  "mango"
]

Answer (score 3):

You could use `python`:

```bsh
python -c '
import json, sys
data = json.load(sys.stdin)
for el in data["properites"]["apps"]:
  print (el)
' < apps.json
```

Answer (score 2):

[jq](/questions/tagged/jq) is the best answer. [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) ships with a JSON module:

```bsh
ruby -rjson -e '
    data = JSON.parse(IO.read(ARGV.shift))
    puts data["properites"]["apps"].join("\n")
' apps.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `grep -P` if available:

```
grep -wF  '"apps":' apps.json | grep -Po '[[,]"\K[^"]*'
```

However, this (and the `awk` solution provided by @Carlos) works only if the input is **exactly** as shown, not if the `json` with same content is formatted differently.

A proper `json` parser , e.g. `jq` or `python`'s `json` module should be preferred!